# Using Jetty 8 memory commitment is increasing constantly until server fails with spring cache

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, jetty

I am using jetty version `8.1.8.v20121106` and have a quite simple spring mvc application deployed. During server uptime the memory commitment is increasing until the server fails.

[image: Memory commitment over time]

Also threads are increasing dramatically over time

[image]

I have a lot of `sleeping` and `waiting for event threads`, as you can see here

```
root      1568  2.9 12.4 14014884 4111368 ?    Sl   10:03   0:07 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -javaagent:/home/ydadmin/newrelic/newrelic.jar -jar /opt/jetty/jetty/star
root      1568  0.7 12.4 14014884 4111368 ?    Sl   10:03   0:02 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -javaagent:/home/ydadmin/newrelic/newrelic.jar -jar /opt/jetty/jetty/star
root      1568  0.0 12.4 14014884 4111368 ?    Sl   10:03   0:00 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -javaagent:/home/ydadmin/newrelic/newrelic.jar -jar /opt/jetty/jetty/star
root      1568  0.0 12.4 14014884 4111368 ?    Sl   10:03   0:00 /usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty/jetty -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -javaagent:/home/ydadmin/newrelic/newrelic.jar -jar /opt/jetty/jetty/star
```

I am assuming it is because of lack in jetty pooling and not closing old connections, but why and how to solve that? My config currently looks like this: http://pastebin.com/NDrUKwCv

How can I find out, what is causing this issue?

**UPDATE**: found with `jsstack` a lot of this threads maybe those can help

http://pastebin.com/7Ybt5NCv

Comment: please tell me, if any additional information are needed...

Comment: thats not jetty doing that, sorry, look to your app, fire it all up in something like jprofiler or yourkit and that should help you sort out what is what.

Comment: I agree with @jessemcconnell, go profile your code with jprofiler or yourkit and find out what is using the memory.  The thread dump is of minimal use and value to you in troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing all parts, where I am using threads it turned out, that I missed out closing a `Executor` which turned out to be bad for garbage collecting.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
// ...
executor.shutdown()
```